# How does proxyMode change beans' lifecycle?

Tags: java, spring

I've been trying to figure out how proxyScope works in a similar but different way to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945163/proxymode-scopedproxymode-target-class-vs-scopedproxymode-interface) topic.

This is my class, which scope I'm playing with. It prints log every time the object is created or the method is invoked:

```
@Component
public class SomeObject {

    public SomeObject() {
        System.out.println("Object created: " + hashCode());
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method invoked: " + hashCode());
    }
}
```

My classes to keep references to the above class:

```
@Component
public class BoxOne {
    @Autowired
    public SomeObject obj;
}

@Component
public class BoxTwo {
    @Autowired
    public SomeObject obj;
}
```

And my main to test it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);

        BoxOne box1 = context.getBean(BoxOne.class);
        BoxTwo box2 = context.getBean(BoxTwo.class);

        SomeObject obj1 = box1.obj;
        SomeObject obj2 = box2.obj;

        System.out.println("hashcode: " + obj1.hashCode());
        System.out.println("hashcode: " + obj2.hashCode());

        obj1.someMethod();
        obj2.someMethod();

        obj1.someMethod();
        obj2.someMethod();
    }
}
```

When I set scope to:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SomeObject { ...
```

I get logs:

```
Object created: 1481818223 (it's while context starting)
...
hashcode: 1508842159
hashcode: 1508842159
Method invoked: 1481818223
Method invoked: 1481818223
Method invoked: 1481818223
Method invoked: 1481818223
```

Why hashcode invoked outside class is different from hashcode invoked inside class?

Then I change scope to:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SomeObject { ...
```

And I get logs:

```
hashcode: -1943188644
hashcode: -1943188644
Object created: 1076984738
Method invoked: 1076984738
Object created: 1810923540
Method invoked: 1810923540
Object created: 1581078471
Method invoked: 1581078471
Object created: 1932332324
Method invoked: 1932332324
```

I get why new object is created every time I invoke a method. What I don't get is:

1. why there are no logs with creation of beans when context starting?
2. if there are no logs (thus no beans created) why hashCode methods return value instead of NullPointerException?
3. why both results of hashCode are the same while I set it as prototype?

This proxyMode is kinda weird thing and I'm afraid I'm not getting it right...

Comment: 1. prototype scoped beans are only created when you request them. You request them after the context has started. 2. because it is created when you requested it. 3. because it is the same object/instance due to prototype scope else you get the proxies hashcode and actual hashcode of internal object.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! So, what we really inject here is not a bean of `SomeObject` class, but a bean of some kind of "ProxyToSomeObject" class. I got that when I added another print to my logs: `System.out.println(obj1.getClass().getSimpleName());` and it produced `SomeObject$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$daba2fac`.