# ProxyMode in Scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a below `singletonbean` which has a `prototype` dependency. In order to get different instances of `Prototype` dependency , I am using `proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` , but still getting the same instances of prototype bean. However using `@Lookup`, I am able to get different. Is this not the correct way to use `proxyMode`, to solve my usecase?

**SpringBootRestAppApplication.java**

```
ApplicationContext a =SpringApplication.run(SpringBootRestAppApplication.class, args);
UserController u1 =a.getBean(UserController.class);
UserController u2 =a.getBean(UserController.class);
System.out.println(u1==u2);  
System.out.println(u1.getU()==u2.getU());
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Component
public class UserController {
    
@Autowired
UserService u;
    

public UserService getU() {
        return u;
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserService {  
}
```

O/P

```
true
true
```

Comment: You're comparing _the proxy object_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected... give it a try

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class UserService {
    public static int instanceID;

    UserService() {
        instanceID++;
    }

    public Integer getInstanceID(){
        return instanceID;
    }
}

@RestController
class UserController {
    final UserService service;
    final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    UserController(UserService service, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.service = service;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @GetMapping("/instanceId")
    public Integer version(){
        return service.getInstanceID();
    }

    @GetMapping("/applic")
    public Integer applicVersion(){
        return applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class).getInstanceID();
    }

}
```

reference: [proxymode-scopedproxymode-target-class-vs-scopedproxymode-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945163/proxymode-scopedproxymode-target-class-vs-scopedproxymode-interface)

Comment: Why is it not working in my example? Is my understanding incorrect of the proxymode?

Comment: @ghostrider improved my answer (see the `/applic` endpoint). It should give the same result.